# What is a function that satisfies the following conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, examples-counterexamples, graphing-functions

I need help to find a well-defined function that satisfies this:

> Let $A\subset  \{0, 1, . . . , 9\}$ be a set and $A_c \subset A$ the subset of all even numbers in the set $A.$
>   Consider a concrete function $f : [−10, 10] \to R $ of your choice with the following
>   properties:
>
> – $f(−10) = 1 = f(10)$
>
> – $f$ is continuous everywhere except at $A_c$
>
> – $f$ is differentiable everywhere except at $A.$

I've done this but is there a different way?
[image: I've done this but is there a different way]

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function defined by $$1+(x+10)(x-10)\frac{\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2(x-3)^2(x-5)^2(x-5)^2(x-9)^2}}{x(x-2)(x-4)(x-6)(x-8)}.$$